# C# Gstreamer-d3d11-overlay Sink.Emit pointer error on render

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, directx, gstreamer

I'm developing a C# WPF application using gstreamer-sharp-netcore(Mingw v1.19.1) on Windows. What we would like to achieve is to be able to render video with hardware acceleration. To avoid the airspace issue in WPF, we are using gstreamer-d3d11-overlay(https://github.com/berglie/gstreamer-d3d11-overlay/).

From the sample, there are 2 ways to initiate rendering the video(MainWindow.cs):

1. Show video by giving the MainWindow handle to GStreamer. This will result in video taking over the whole the WPF. This piece of code works, but we won't be able to add any WPF controls.

```
    var windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
    _playback = new Playback(windowHandle, _enableOverlay);
```

2. Another way what we would like to use is to make a image object in WPF. Create a D3dImageEx and D3D11TestScene and attach it to the image object.

```
    _d3DImageEx = new D3DImageEx();
    _D3D11Scene = new D3D11TestScene(1920, 1080);
    d3dScene.Source = _d3DImageEx;
    /* Set the backbuffer, which is a ID3D11Texture2D pointer */
    IntPtr renderTarget = _D3D11Scene.GetRenderTarget();
    IntPtr backBuffer = _d3DImageEx.CreateBackBuffer(D3DResourceTypeEx.ID3D11Texture2D, renderTarget);

    _d3DImageEx.Lock();
    _d3DImageEx.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, backBuffer, _enableSoftwareFallback);
    _d3DImageEx.Unlock();

    _playback = new Playback(IntPtr.Zero, _enableOverlay);
    _playback.OnDrawSignalReceived += VideoSink_OnBeginDraw;

    CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
```

When this is successfully initialized, Gstreamer will render the video and fire the OnDrawSignalReceived:

```
    private void VideoSink_OnBeginDraw(Element sink, GLib.SignalArgs args)
    {
        var sharedHandle = _D3D11Scene.GetSharedHandle();
        _ = sink.Emit("draw", sharedHandle, (UInt32)2, (UInt64)0, (UInt64)0);
    }
```

On the line: "sink.Emit" we get a error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  HResult=0x80131604
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at Gst.DynamicSignal.OnMarshal(IntPtr closure, Value& retval, UInt32 argc, IntPtr argsPtr, IntPtr ihint, IntPtr data)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Gst.DynamicSignal.Emit(GLib.Object, string, object[])
    Gst.Object.Emit(string, object[])
    TestHacoustoGst2D3D11WpfApp.MainWindow.VideoSink_OnBeginDraw(Gst.Element, GLib.SignalArgs) in MainWindow.xaml.cs
    TestHacoustoGst2D3D11WpfApp.Playback.VideoSink_OnBeginDraw(object, GLib.SignalArgs) in Playback.cs

Inner Exception 1:
ApplicationException: Invalid parameter type: expected , got System.IntPtr
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? That would be greatly appreciated :)

We're also thinking about using OpenTK, but we have to see how to efficiently share the OpenGL Texture from glimagesink to OpenTk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed in GtkSharp: https://github.com/GLibSharp/GtkSharp/pull/52

I assume that you are using GstSharp NuGet package which per today has not been updated with this fix yet.

To temporarily solve the issue, I have uploaded a unofficial hot fix to NuGet, search for "GstSharp.HotFix".

https://www.nuget.org/packages/GstSharp.Hotfix/

Edit: Please make sure that you uninstall the official GstSharp package if you are using the hotfix package.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you help me get started? I have added nuget packages GstSharp.Hotfix(1.19.0.1) and GstSharp(1.18.0). But my visual studio can't find:
`using Gst;`

Comment: When using GstSharp.Hotfix(1.19.0.1)  you don't need GstSharp(1.18.0), you will get a namespace conflict. Uninstall package GstSharp(1.18.0) and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: We recompiled this GTK master branche and included it in our project and everything works! Tested in v1.19.1 with Gstreamer-sharp-netcore.

Comment: @berglie Can you please explain how to build on Windows? Would really appreciate latest GStreamer x64 support.

Comment: @superware From the [documentation](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp) it looks like it only supports builds on Linux and Mac OS X. You can build on Windows, it is just more complicated. From the documentation, "Add an easy way to compile on Windows" is on the roadmap. If you still want to go down this road, i recommend [talking with the GStreamer developers](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/dev/).  I submitted an issue now in the [gstreamer-sharp project](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/-/issues/62), maybe someone can look into it.

Comment: Thanks @berglie, any news? :|